# What are performance techniques used with ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm developing an iOS app targeting iOS5 and using ARC. Testers complaining about high CPU usage (wonder if they mean memory usage).

Do I have to nil out every property on viewDidUnload? And what about iOS6, where viewDidUnload is deprecated?

Testers complaining about UIPickers that are open among with new view cotrollers.
I call removeViewControlleerFromSuperview on them, what else could I do?

Comment: There are no performance techniques associated specifically with ARC. You write your code and ARC will work out how to dealloc stuff at compile time. Nothing is done at run time with ARC. You would be best putting your app through Instruments (Profile the app) and you will see what is doing what in the app.

Comment: @Fogmeister Or, we could argue that ARC's performance technique is that it's ARC and not garbage collection (which would be slow as heck on low-memory platforms like the iPhone).

Comment: Very true. lol. Either way is valid.

Comment: So the arc is arc is perfect and I shouldn't worry about niling out any resources?

Comment: weak references affect performance somehow, as also said in one the latest talk at WWDC, but agree with the other, if the see high CPU usage most likely there are other problems.

Comment: If testers are complaining then I would suggest that you use Instruments to find potential bottlenecks.

Comment: Yeah, I find it hard to use them. Can I use them with real device?